# Quasar q-dialog sizing

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, quasar

I have 5 dialog on the same page and 3 are different.  The only way I have been able to control the dialog border is with

```
.q-dialog {
  z-index: 999999999;
}
.q-dialog__inner--minimized > div {
  @media (min-width: 1000px) {
    min-width: 1000px;
    min-height: 500px;
  }
}
```

However I've assigned classes to each of the dialogs but it does not seem to change the size.  I'm very weak with CSS so I may not have it structured correctly

```
.myDialogFilter {
  .q-dialog {
    z-index: 999999999;
  }
  .q-dialog__inner--minimized > div {
    @media (min-width: 500px) {
      min-width: 500px;
      min-height: 500px;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:  I changed .myDialogFilter { to #myDialogFilter { and added an id and that works.  Is my class structure wrong?

Does anyone know where can I find all of the q-dialog css settings?

Comment: Inspect element in your browser dev tools might help you figure out the css classes

Answer (score 0):

Using Tailwindcss you can add the !max-w-none on the class in the q-card like this.

```
<q-card class="!max-w-none !w-[800px]">
```

or

```
<q-card class="!w-0 min-w-[400px]">
```

This removes the max-width that the q-card has. If you don't use TailwindCss then you can set a class using plain CSS like this.

```
.myClass {
max-width: none !important;
width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).